# Simple typescript error that cannot pass props to a functional component

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass a prop to a functional component (uses typescript) and I'm getting a rendering error but don't know why.

Here is the file that imports the component:

```
<ActiveCheckbox active={true} />
```

And here's the component file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@chakra-ui/core";

export const ActiveCheckbox: React.FC = (active: boolean) => {
  return <Checkbox variantColor="teal" mr={2} isChecked={active}></Checkbox>;
};
```

And the error:

```
TypeScript error in /src/components/active-checkbox.tsx(4,14):
Type '(active: boolean) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'active' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.  TS2322
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I've also tried appending `<any>` after `React.FC` but to no avail.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Try `ActiveCheckbox: React.FC<{active: boolean}> = ({ active }) => ...`